# Multiply by 46 using only add/mov/shift instructions? Ideas on how to improve my code

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I'm learning Asm.8086 on my own from an online course and there was a task to square the number 46(46^2=2116) by only using add, mov and shift commands.

I've managed to do so but I would love to know if I could have done it better :)

variables:

```
 X dw 46d
 Y dw 0
```

code:

```
mov cx, [X]
shl cx, 5 // cx=1472d
add [Y], cx // Y=1472d
sar cx, 2 // cx=368d
add [Y], cx // Y=1840d
sar cx, 1 // cx=184d
add [Y], cx // Y=2024d
sar cx, 1 // cx=92d
add [Y], cx // Y=2116d
```

At the end I have checked the variable Y and it was 2116 as needed, but because this is the first time I'm doing this on Assembly I believe there is a better way to do such thing (taking in consideration the limits of using only add, mov and shift commands  :)

Comment: Depends on what the assignment is exactly. You did not square `X`, you multiplied it by 46. Of course if `X` is 46 that is the same, but if the code needs to be actually squaring it should work for other values as well. Otherwise if the assignment is to _"square the number 46 by only using add, mov and shift commands"_ then of course you can just `mov [Y], 2116`.

Comment: I get your point, it is not a code that suppose to square a number but to multiply 46 with 46 which is the task if I understood it correctly. Translation of the assingment would be "define X to be 46 and calculate into Y 46*46 using only add, mov and shift"

Comment: Just move 2116 into Y.

Comment: Have your assembler do the calculation: `mov word [Y], 46 * 46`

Comment: Otherwise, use a register (e.g. `ax`) for the temporary result, and only store to `Y` when you're done with the calculation.  When doing `add [Y],..` that makes it read Y from memory and also write it: the instruction is ~slower, and takes more space to encode than a register target.

Comment: Also, that sequence doesn't clear Y to start, so were it run twice, it will have Y at 2116*2=4232.  I would target `ax`, and eliminate the first `add` with `mov ax` instead -- that will both start from scratch plus remove a number of memory operations.

Comment: That assignment wording would allow `X equ 46`, to define it as an assemble-time constant.  Then `mov word ptr [Y],  X*X` will get the assembler to do the math for you at assemble time.  The `*` operator isn't a run-time computation.  It would be intentionally mis-interpreting the assignment, I think, but only about as much as hard-coding `mov word ptr [Y], 2116`.  Even if you do want to use runtime computation to multiply by 46, you can still start with `mov ax, X` using `X equ 46` instead of pointlessly loading a constant from memory.

Comment: `46` is `0b101110`.  It has quite a few set bits, but only two zeroed bits below the most-significant,  So `x*46` is `x*64 - x*16 - 2*x`.  Oh, but they don't want you to use `sub`, only `add`, and other than lookup tables, there isn't a good way to negate a number to do subtraction.

Comment: Probably don't start with a left shift.  If you had a larger input, that could throw away some bits.  Also, `sar` does sign-extension, so it has overflow problems for smaller numbers than `shr`.  Unless you specifically want an arithmetic right shift, shifting in copies of the MSB, normally use `shr`.

Answer (score 2):

> ... to know if I could have done it better.

> ```
> mov cx, [X]
> add [Y], cx
> add [Y], cx
> add [Y], cx
> add [Y], cx
> ```

Prefer the AX register to read from or write to memory. The encoding is shorter.
Don't `add` the very first value to the *Y* variable, but `mov` it there.
Build the result in a register and store the register in the *Y* variable.

> **8086** ... a task to square the number 46 by only using `add`, `mov` and `shift`

> ```
> shl cx, 5
> sar cx, 2
> ```

The 8086 does not allow shifting by an immediate count. Either shift once or shift using a count specified in the CL register.

46d == 00101110b

```
    46 * 46
<=> 46 * (2 + 4 + 8 + 32)
<=> (46 * 2) + (46 * 4) + (46 * 8) + (46 * 32)
<=> (46 << 1) + (46 << 2) + (46 << 3) + (46 << 5)
```

An 8086 solution in 24 bytes:

```
mov  ax, [X]    ; AX =   46
shl  ax, 1      ; AX =   92
mov  bx, ax     ; BX =   92
shl  ax, 1      ; AX =  184
add  bx, ax     ; BX =  276
shl  ax, 1      ; AX =  368
add  bx, ax     ; BX =  644
shl  ax, 1      ; AX =  736
shl  ax, 1      ; AX = 1472
add  ax, bx     ; AX = 2116
mov  [Y], ax    ;  Y = 2116
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're allowed to use `sub`:

```
;compute 2(16x+7x) = 2*23x = 46x
mov cx,46
mov dx,cx   ;back up cx
shl cx,4    ;46 * 16
mov bx,dx   ;back up dx
shl dx,3    ;46 * 8 (one too high, we'll reduce it to 46 * 7)
sub dx,bx   ;46 * 7
add dx,cx   ;(46 * 16) + (46 * 7)
add dx,dx   ;2 * ((46 * 16) + (46 * 7))
```

If not:

```
mov ax,46
mov bx,ax
mov cx,ax
mov dx,ax  ;four copies of the input.

shl ax,4
shl bx,2
shl cx,1
;(16x + 4x + 2x + x)
add ax,bx
add ax,cx
add ax,dx
add ax,ax ;multiply by 2, result is in ax
```

Comment: What register is your result supposed to be in?  Your last 2 instructions update different registers, so only one of them is affecting the output.  `add cx,dx` does CX+=DX.  `add dx,dx` does DX <<= 1, which makes sense for the final `*2`.  Also note the assignment didn't mention `sub` as an instruction you could use; a version with `sub` is useful to show future readers an efficient way without that restriction.

Comment: Result was in `dx`. This was meant to be inlined

Comment: Ok, looks like `add cx,dx` was supposed to be `add dx, cx`, given the comments.  Otherwise the stuff you compute in CX never feeds into DX.

Comment: Yeah it was, my bad.